# Support for functional pattern matching in Elm

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, elm

In Elm is there a way to pattern match the arguments of a function to multiple definitions like in Haskell?

Example from Haskell:

```
factorial :: Int ->
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no equivalent of that syntax in Elm.

The easiest way to achieve similar behavior would be using pattern matching with [`case`](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#conditionals) statement.

Please consider the following example:

```elm
factorial : Int -> Int
factorial n =
  case n of
    0 ->
      1
    _ ->
      n * factorial (n - 1)
```

The `_` from the example above serves as a wildcard to match any pattern, in this case, it's any integer different from `0`

Comment: Thanks that worked! A little more verbose but functional.